# Read USB Magstripe reader through ssh

Tags: python, ssh, keyboard, raspberry-pi

I made a python program for my pi that detects strings from my usb card reader(it acts like a USB keyboard) and writes them to a file. I realized that if I ssh into the program to run it, the program does not work. My guess is that because my program takes raw input typed into the console, it won't work if I turn it on through ssh. Can anyone help me on this?

Below is my program:

```
import datetime
import time

card = raw_input()
t = datetime.datetime.now()
while True:
    f = open("Laptop Sign Out" + '.txt', 'a')
    f.write("Card Number: " + card[1:10] + " Time: " + t.strftime("%m-%d-%Y $
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(';')
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `evdev` library, which allows to redirect events generated in the kernel directly to user code.

Look at this example:

```
>>> from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes
>>> dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event1')

>>> print(dev)
device /dev/input/event1, name "Dell Dell USB Keyboard", phys "usb-0000:00:12.1-2/input0"

>>> for event in dev.read_loop():
...     if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
...         print(categorize(event))
... # pressing 'a' and holding 'space'
key event at 1337016188.396030, 30 (KEY_A), down
key event at 1337016188.492033, 30 (KEY_A), up
key event at 1337016189.772129, 57 (KEY_SPACE), down
key event at 1337016190.275396, 57 (KEY_SPACE), hold
key event at 1337016190.284160, 57 (KEY_SPACE), up
```

Additional reading is [here](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events)

A little bit different way described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/562434/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-hosts-keyboard-when-connected-via-ssh)